# How to hide Selenium CHrome Driver Server Command Window in Go / Golang

Tags: google-chrome, go, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When i launch my builded exe file with `-ldflags -H=windowsgui` the programm file runs hidden however Chrome Driver pops out. How can I get rid of it using Go programming language?

my code sample

````
import (
    "github.com/tebeka/selenium"
    "github.com/tebeka/selenium/chrome"
)

func main() error {
    // Run Chrome browser
    service, err := selenium.NewChromeDriverService("./chromedriver", 4444)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer service.Stop()

    caps := selenium.Capabilities{}
    caps.AddChrome(chrome.Capabilities{Args: []string{
        "window-size=1920x1080",
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
        "disable-gpu",
        // "--headless",  // comment out this line to see the browser
    }})

    driver, err := selenium.NewRemote(caps, "")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    driver.Get("https://www.google.com")
}```
````